# is it possible to install a .ova file which contains an operating system?

Tags: virtual-machine, operating-systems, debian-jessie

have an *.ova file* wich i use in my virtual machine, but i want **to install it** on my computer as an "independant" OS and not within a virtual machine. Is that possible ?

PS: the ova file already contains the programs i need.

Comment: Did you Google this at all? What have you tried? There are several tutorials on the internet to do exactly what you are asking...

Comment: all i found was how to use it in the virtual machine but i want to install it as my second operating system and i wanna use this file because it already contains programs i need.   thanks for your help

Comment: You have to deploy it as a VM then convert it to a physical machine, you can't just convert an OVA deployment file to install media for a physical machine.